# jQuery: Translate from built-in XPath expression to standard jQuery expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xpath

I have the following table:

```
<h1>Selected Shakespear Plays</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>As You Like It</td>
            <td>Comedy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>All's Well that Ends Well</td>
            <td>Comedy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Henry V</td>
            <td>History</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then the below script that uses XPath expressions. I believe that when the book I am following was published, XPath was built into jQuery, but it has since been moved out into the [jquery-xpath](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath) plugin.

```
$("tr:not([th]):odd").addClass("odd");
$("tr:not([th]):even").addClass("even");
$("td:contains('Henry')").addClass("highlight");
$("thead tr").addClass("table-heading").removeClass("even");
```

This is intended to add the classes `odd` and `even` to all `tr` elements that don't contain a `th` element, i.e. to all rows except the first, header row. It does not work, the header row, even with `th` elements still gets the class `even`. This is why I had to add `.removeClass("even");` to the last line of code.

Is the XPath query `not([th])` or just `[th]`? Then, how do I translate this jQuery "XPath statement":

```
$("tr:not([th]):odd").addClass("odd");
```

to a standard jQuery statement that fetches all `tr` that don't contain any `th`?

Comment: To sidestep the issue of skipping the `th` elements, could you not just select all the `tr` within the `tbody`? If you still did want to exclude the `tr` that contain a `th`, combine `:not` and `:contains`: `$('tr:not(:contains(th))')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have already successfully done this by your first method, but I'm keen on following the book closely, and it doesn't use `thead` and `tbody`. I also wanted to learn how to exclude the `th` more or less like they did, as I have not previously known how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: jQuery has not supported XPath for a very long time, in fact around 10 years since the days of 1.2/1.3, so the book you're reading appears incredibly outdated. The modern alternative is to use the pseudo selectors I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, it's a big pity though, because the book is so thorough in its detail and also more comprehensive than most others I have used. That's why I chose it despite a 2007 publication date.